# Which component is responsible for adjusting the CPU multiplier?

Tags: cpu, cpu-speed, underclock

I am preparing a school presentation about underclocking/overclocking and have read several articles about the CPU multiplier during my research. Some of the articles have claimed that the CPU itself adjusts the multiplier, others have written that the BIOS firmware or the OS adjusts it. I have not saved the link to the last statement, but most of the answers here in [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/62353/how-can-a-cpu-dynamically-change-its-clock-frequency) forum and others seem to imply that the CPU itself is responsible for adjusting the multiplier/ frequency.

In my understanding, the maximum CPU multiplier is determined by the CPU's maximum performance. A CPU that has 3,5 Gigahertz combined with a system that runs at 100 Megahertz base clock speed has a maximum multiplier of 35. The motherboard/BIOS or the OS can directly control the multiplier by sending instructions to certain registers within the CPU so it runs fewer instructions per second. Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumption is not correct. The CPU controller is entirely autonomous and
handles by itself all decisions involving the total power draw of
the CPU and its division among cores (for when turbo mode is active on
one core).

The OS can decide to park certain CPU cores. It also has parameters for
the allowed maximum percentage of the CPU to use, which it handles by
setting CPU quotas for the processes.

The BIOS can effect changes to the motherboard that impact the CPU as regarding
voltage and other factors connected to under/over-clocking.
These parameters are static in nature, unlike the others which are dynamic
and adaptive.

Comment: For a good citation to support the fact that this is handled by the CPU but able to be influenced by the OS or system firmware see https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/processors/core/8th-gen-core-family-datasheet-vol-1.html section 4.2.1.2 and onwards.

Comment: `Intel Speed Shift Technology is an energy efficient method of frequency control by the 
hardware rather than relying on OS control. OS is aware of available hardware P-states 
and request a desired P-state or it can let Hardware determine the P-state. The OS 
request is based on its workload requirements and awareness of processor capabilities. 
Processor decision is based on the different system constraints for example: Workload 
demand, thermal limits while taking into consideration the minimum and maximum 
levels and activity window of performance requested by the operating system.`